# How do you write engineering calculations in c# with itext to PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, equation

I need to write code for quite a few equations in C# and then export to PDF using itext. One example is below:

b_h = (c^^3 * d_1) / (1 + v^2)

Where _ denotes: subscript
      ^^ denotes: superscript

Any ideas of where I could find a resource so that I could provide a neat version of this equation in a PDF, i.e. as you would see a proper engineering equation in a textbook?

Comment: Microsoft Office has an Equation Editor.  From Word use INSERT EQUATION.

Comment: What operators do you want? Because your example includes more than just the subscript and superscript you mention.

Comment: Basically add, subtract, divide, multiply, power, root. Nothing too complex for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a proof of concept at iText that handles formulas.
However, we are not yet ready to deploy this in production.

There are 3 scenarios you could now take:

- wait for iText to develop this
- develop it yourself (I will give some pointers as to how we built our proof of concept)
- use an external piece of software that renders formula to images, and then insert the image into the PDF using iText

If you are going to develop this yourself, our proof of concept was built using the pdfHTML code basis as a start.

Using antlr we built a grammar that accepts mathematical expressions and converts them into a DOM-like structure.

The modified DOM can be walked (just like pdfHTML would walk a regular HTML DOM model) and output the appropriate elements whenever it encounters a node of a certain type.

You will need to write custom renderers for some types of nodes.
E.g.

- subscript
- superscript
- root
- power
- fraction

But all in all, it should not take more than a few days work to get a basic implementation going.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am a complete novice so I think option 2 is out for me! Do you know what sort of timescale itext are looking at for option 1? (I.e. months or years?) In the meantime option 3 is looking like the best for me short-term, although I have done many calculation sheets in Excel where I just used the underline function for division, so maybe I will just try and do this directly in iText.

Comment: Currently we've made a proof of concept, and we are now weighing the options. Implementing it ourselves, or using an existing framework. But it is on our roadmap to have this functionality. That's all I can say. I can not offer a timeframe.

Comment: @dazedandconfused Please also be aware that apart from the decision regarding roadmap priorities, we'll also have to make a decision whether or not we'll open source this or offer this as a closed source add-on. Are you already an iText *customer* or planning to become a customer?